# ExcelJS: doesn't save file properly

Tags: exceljs

I wrote an script and here's an snippet from my code:

```
let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.readFile('./input.xlsx');
await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./output.xlsx');
console.log('file saved!');
```

I know how async/await works and there is no error!
the `input.xlsx` is a valid excel file. but the `output.xlsx` can't be opened by libreOffice or Microsoft Excel.
I should notice that if I comment `await workbook.xlsx.readFile('./input.xlsx');`, in this situation also the `output.xlsx` can't be read too!

It's an strange issue for me! I used `exceljs` many many times but I don't know why it's happening now!

`exceljs` version: `3.9.0`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that exceljs hasn't implemented at least one feature used in `input.xlsx`.
Similar situation I had with images some times ago and fixed by PR: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/pull/702

Could I ask you to create an issue on GH?

If you want to find what exactly went wrong:

1. unzip `input.xlsx`
2. unzip `output.xlsx`
3. check diff between.

You can also upload `input.xlsx` here, it should help to find a bug reason.

I think also, check any other version of exceljs may be helpful.

Comment: yeah I added [#1286](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1286). also I provided more information about the issue there.